# Install latest composer dependencies

Tags: composer-php

I have private repository in which we have a composer.json file.

```
{
  "name": "vendor/package",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0",
    "ether/splash": "^v3.0.2",
    "ether/simplemap": "^v3.3.4",
    "aelvan/imager": "^v2.1.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "craftcms/redactor": "^2.1.6",
    "craftcms/mandrill": "^1.2.0",
    "sebastianlenz/linkfield": "^1.0.15",
    "solspace/craft3-freeform": "^2.4.1",
    "nystudio107/craft-minify": "^1.2.9",
    "nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "^3.1.26",
    "pieterxjan/slack-error-notifications": "^1.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

When I perform a `composer create-project vendor/package .`, it only installs the given requirements as specified in the `composer.json` file.

In case I want the latest dependencies, I need to perform a `composer update` after the install is complete. I wonder if there is another way of installing the latest dependencies with only the `composer create-package` command.

The inspiration of my bootstrap package is [Andrew Welch's craft repo](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft). If I install his repo as documented in the readme, I immediately get the latest dependencies, whilst the dependences specified in the `composer.json` file are older versions.

Is there some setting I'm forgetting that takes care of this?

Comment: Do you have `composer.lock` in this repo?

Comment: @rob006 No, there is no lockfile in the repository.